# Converting Java 1.8 lambdas to Java 1.7 on gs-uploading-files Spring Boot example

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, lambda

I am running through some exercises on https://spring.io/ Spring Boot.

Doing example https://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/ and it works fine when I use Java 8, but unfortunately the code I am wrapping in a web service requires Java 7.  I have listed all of the erroring code, can someone help me convert the lambdas to 1.7 compliant code and replace the new libraries (java.util.stream.Stream and java.util.stream.Collectors).

**Application.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties(StorageProperties.class)
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    CommandLineRunner init(StorageService storageService) {
        return (args) -> {
            storageService.deleteAll();
            storageService.init();
        };
    }
}
```

> return (args) -> errors out saying "use source -8 or higher to enable
>   lambda expressions"

**FileUploadController.java**

```
import java.util.stream.Collectors

//..

@GetMapping("/")
public String listUploadedFiles(Model model) throws IOException {

    model.addAttribute("files", storageService
            .loadAll()
            .map(path ->
                    MvcUriComponentsBuilder
                            .fromMethodName(FileUploadController.class, "serveFile", path.getFileName().toString())
                            .build().toString())
            .collect(Collectors.toList()));

    return "uploadForm";
}
```

> package java.util.stream does not exist
>
> type loadAll() is erroneous
>
> errors out saying "use source -8 or higher to enable
>   lambda expressions"

**FileSystemStorageService.java**

```
@Override
public Stream<Path> loadAll() {
    try {
        return Files.walk(this.rootLocation, 1)
                .filter(path -> !path.equals(this.rootLocation))
                .map(path -> this.rootLocation.relativize(path));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new StorageException("Failed to read stored files", e);
    }

}
```

> cannot find symbol walk
>
> errors out saying "use source -8 or higher to enable
>   lambda expressions"

**StorageService.java**

```
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public interface StorageService {

    void init();

    void store(MultipartFile file);

    Stream<Path> loadAll();

    Path load(String filename);

    Resource loadAsResource(String filename);

    void deleteAll();

}
```

> package java.util.stream does not exist

Comment: Of course it doesn't exist. Stream is a Java 8 API. Forget that you can use it with Java 7.

Comment: you could convert lamda expression to anonymous class, and streams to the old ugly iterations (might not be feasible sometimes)

Comment: *"the code I am wrapping in a web service requires Java 7"* Why does it *require* Java 7?

Comment: Requires Java 7 cause is does not work correctly when Java 8 is chosen.  Signal analysis software written by smart people, would be easier to rewrite the spring boot code then their stuff.

Answer (score 6):

Bulltorious, I'm sorry for your bounty but you really have only very few choices. Stream API was added only in Java 8 and thus does not exist in the Java 7. You can work-around lambda-related issues by manually writting anonymous classes or  even almost automatically (see [Retrolambda](https://github.com/orfjackal/retrolambda)). However with the Stream API you only have two choices:

1. Backport Stream API to Java 7 manually. Or use someone else attempt to backport such as [streamsupport project](https://sourceforge.net/projects/streamsupport/) on SourceForge (or copy on [GitHub](https://github.com/streamsupport/streamsupport))
2. Get rid of the Stream API and use older Java 7 classes.

**Update** (replace `Files.walk`)

In case your `Files.walk` is the only place you use Java-8-specific API, you can replace it with Java 7 API relatively easily:

```java
interface PathNameMapper
{
    String mapPath(Path path);
}


List<String> loadAll(PathNameMapper mapper)
{
    try
    {
        List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();

        Files.walkFileTree(rootLocation, EnumSet.noneOf(FileVisitOption.class), 1, new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>()
        {
            @Override
            public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException
            {
                if (!rootLocation.equals(file))
                {
                    result.add(mapper.mapPath(rootLocation.relativize(file)));
                }
                return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
            }
        });


        return result;
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        throw new StorageException("Failed to read stored files", e);
    }
}
```

and then your `listUploadedFiles` would become something like

```java
@GetMapping ("/")
public String listUploadedFiles(Model model) throws IOException
{

    model.addAttribute("files", storageService
            .loadAll(new PathNameMapper()
            {
                @Override
                public String mapPath(Path path)
                {
                    return MvcUriComponentsBuilder
                            .fromMethodName(FileUploadController.class, "serveFile", path.getFileName().toString())
                            .build().toString();
                }
            }));

    return "uploadForm";
}
```

**Update 2** (labmda -> anonymous class conversion)

And just for completeness an example of how to convert lambda to an anonymous class manually:

```java
@Bean
CommandLineRunner init(StorageService storageService)
{
    return new CommandLineRunner()
    {
        @Override
        public void run(String... args) throws Exception
        {
            storageService.deleteAll();
            storageService.init();              
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Thank you SergGr.  While all the solutions worked, I gave you the bounty because you corrected the other 2 solutions as well.

Answer (score 6):

You can update your methods like below to Java 7 variant. All the test cases are passing.

**Application.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties(StorageProperties.class)
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    CommandLineRunner init(StorageService storageService) {
        return new CommandLineRunner() {
          @Override
           public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
            storageService.deleteAll();
            storageService.init();
           }
       };
    }
}
```

**FileUploadController.java**

```
@GetMapping("/")
    public String listUploadedFiles(Model model) throws IOException {
        List<Path> paths = storageService.loadAll();
        List<String> sPaths = new ArrayList<>(paths.size());
        for (Path path : paths) {
            sPaths.add(MvcUriComponentsBuilder
                        .fromMethodName(FileUploadController.class, "serveFile", path.getFileName().toString())
                        .build().toString());
        }
        model.addAttribute("files", sPaths);
        return "uploadForm";
    }
```

Updated the method implementation to use `DirectoryStream` to simple listing all the files.

**FileSystemStorageService.java**

```
@Override
public List<Path> loadAll() {
   List<Path> rPaths = new ArrayList<>();
   try (DirectoryStream<Path> stream = Files.newDirectoryStream(this.rootLocation)) {
       for (Path entry: stream) {
             rPaths.add(rootLocation.relativize(entry));
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
       throw new StorageException("Failed to read stored files", e);
    }
    return rPaths;
}
```

**StorageService.java**

```
public interface StorageService {

    void init();

    void store(MultipartFile file);

    List<Path> loadAll();

    Path load(String filename);

    Resource loadAsResource(String filename);

    void deleteAll();

}
```

**FileUploadTests**

```
 @Test
    public void shouldListAllFiles() throws Exception {
        given(this.storageService.loadAll())
                .willReturn(Arrays.asList(Paths.get("first.txt"), Paths.get("second.txt")));

        this.mvc.perform(get("/"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(model().attribute("files",
                        Matchers.contains("http://localhost/files/first.txt", "http://localhost/files/second.txt")));
    }
```

**FileSystemStorageServiceTest**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class FileSystemStorageServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    private StorageService storageService;

    @Test
    public void loadAll() throws Exception {
        MockMultipartFile multipartFile =
                new MockMultipartFile("file", "test.txt", "text/plain", "Spring Framework".getBytes());
        storageService.store(multipartFile);
        List<Path> paths = storageService.loadAll();
        assertThat(paths.size()).isEqualTo(1);
    }

}
```

Update `TestCompare` with `rootLocation` set to `FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(".")`

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class TestCompare {

    @Configuration
    @ComponentScan(basePackages = {"hello.storage"})
    @EnableConfigurationProperties(StorageProperties.class)
    static class ContextConfiguration{}

    @Autowired
    private StorageService storageService;

    @Test
    public void loadAllDirectoryStreamVsloadAllWalkFileWithDepth1() throws Exception {
        List<Path> paths1 = storageService.loadAllDirectoryStream();
        List<Path> paths2 = storageService.loadAllWalkFileWithDepth1();
        assertThat(paths1.size()).isEqualTo(paths2.size());

    }

}
```

I've added two methods just for testing purposes. One using `DirectoryStream` and another using  `WalkFileTree` with `maxDepth` set to 1. Both of them works the same.

```
   @Override
    public List<Path> loadAllDirectoryStream() {
        List<Path> rPaths = new ArrayList<>();
        try (DirectoryStream<Path> stream = Files.newDirectoryStream(this.rootLocation)) {
            for (Path entry: stream) {
                //if(!Files.isDirectory(entry))
                    rPaths.add(rootLocation.relativize(entry));
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new StorageException("Failed to read stored files", e);
        }
        return rPaths;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Path> loadAllWalkFileWithDepth1() {
        List<Path> rPaths = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            Files.walkFileTree(rootLocation, EnumSet.noneOf(FileVisitOption.class), 1, new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
                @Override
                public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
                    if (!rootLocation.equals(file)) {
                        rPaths.add(rootLocation.relativize(file));
                    }
                    return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
                }
            });
            return rPaths;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new StorageException("Failed to read stored files", e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Veeram, do your tests actually pass when you don't mock `loadAll`? In my tests for your `loadAll` if I defind `rootLocation` as `FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(".")` I just get an empty List instead of folder structure of my project. And if I use `FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(".").toAbsolute()`, I get back a list of folders on the path from the root to the project's folder (i.e. path components of the project folder). I don't think you can work around the need to actually collect the data from inside of a `FileVisitor`

Comment: You are right. Thank you for verifying and commenting. I assumed it would work similar to java 8 `walk` method but now I've updated the code to use `DirectoryStream` which seems the right fit for listing the files in the directory for OP's use case and added a test case for the `loadAll` method.

Comment: well if it worked that simple, my code wouldn't be that complicated. And now you essentially have to copy my code anyway

Comment: @SergGr I've added a test case comparing `DirectoryStream` approach against the `WalkFileTree` with `maxDepth` set to `1` and both of them behaves similarly.

Answer (score 3):

Building on [SergGr's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43127703/converting-java-1-8-lambdas-to-java-1-7-on-gs-uploading-files-spring-boot-exampl/43164211#43164211) and [Veeram's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43127703/converting-java-1-8-lambdas-to-java-1-7-on-gs-uploading-files-spring-boot-exampl/43164460#43164460) excellent answers I'll show an alternative implementation of the two critical methods that depend on the Java 8 Stream API (`loadAll()` and `listUploadedFiles()`) using the [streamsupport](https://github.com/stefan-zobel/streamsupport) backport of the Stream API already mentioned in SergGr's answer.

This implementation doesn't use lambdas (though that could easily be done using [retrolambda](https://github.com/orfjackal/retrolambda)) because it is probably overkill to introduce `retrolambda` for only a couple of lambda expressions.

**FileSystemStorageService.java**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.DirectoryStream;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;

import java8.util.Spliterator;
import java8.util.Spliterators;
import java8.util.function.Function;
import java8.util.function.Predicate;
import java8.util.stream.Stream;
import java8.util.stream.StreamSupport;

public class FileSystemStorageService implements StorageService {

    @Override
    public Stream<Path> loadAll() {
        try {
            final DirectoryStream<Path> ds = Files.newDirectoryStream(rootLocation);
            return StreamSupport
                    .stream(Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(
                            ds.iterator(), Spliterator.DISTINCT), false)
                    .onClose(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            try {
                                ds.close();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                throw new StorageException(
                                        "Failed to close stream", e);
                            }
                        }
                    })
                    .filter(new Predicate<Path>() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean test(Path path) {
                            return !path.equals(rootLocation);
                        }
                    }).map(new Function<Path, Path>() {
                        @Override
                        public Path apply(Path path) {
                            return rootLocation.relativize(path);
                        }
                    });
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new StorageException("Failed to read stored files", e);
        }
    }
}
```

**FileUploadController.java**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Path;

import java8.util.function.Function;
import java8.util.stream.Collectors;
import java8.util.stream.Stream;

import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.MvcUriComponentsBuilder;

public class FileUploadController {

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String listUploadedFiles(Model model) throws IOException {

        Stream<Path> stream = null;
        try {
            stream = storageService.loadAll();
            model.addAttribute("files",
                    stream.map(new Function<Path, String>() {
                        public String apply(Path path) {
                            return MvcUriComponentsBuilder
                                    .fromMethodName(FileUploadController.class,
                                            "serveFile",
                                            path.getFileName().toString()).build()
                                    .toString();
                        }
                    }).collect(Collectors.toList()));
        } finally {
            if (stream != null) {
                stream.close();
            }
        }

        return "uploadForm";
    }
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sourceforge.streamsupport</groupId>
    <artifactId>streamsupport</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Hope this helps you get going. **Disclaimer:** Note that I haven't tested this!

Comment: Sartorius, unfortunately `Path` as `Iterable<Path>` doesn't work this way. It just iterates over parts of the path rather than children of the current directory. That's why you really need to use `walkFileTree` and `FileVisitor`

Comment: @SergGr Thanks for correcting me. I was obviously too concerned with the Stream aspect to get it right in the first place. Revised and hopefully a bit more functional now.

Answer (score 1):

The lambdas are in fact single-method interfaces, called functional interfaces. You can easily convert most of lambda expression to interface simply by following your IDE code completions. For example, let's take a filter method:

```
filter(Predicate<? super T> predicate)
```

As you can see, filter method simply accepts an instance of Predicate interface, which has test method that looks like this:

```
boolean test(T t)

Evaluates this predicate on the given argument.

Parameters:
    t - the input argument
Returns:
    true if the input argument matches the predicate, otherwise false
```

You can easily create your own Predicate implementation and use it while iterating your examples. For instance, you can create your own generic `filter` method which takes a `Collection` and your predicate strategy which will be applied for every element. You can also use Guava `Function` interfaces, which were used before Java 8. Here you have some explanation how to use it: https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/FunctionalExplained.

To sum it up - you can use Guava or create your own wrappers for every example. You can simulate streams simply by iterating your collections. Converting lambdas is a no-brainer, since you realize they are just single-method interfaces.